# C++ boost threads are locking GUI thread in MFC

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, nonblocking

does boost threading has a way to wait for threads to complete without blocking message pump of GUI?

Answer (score 3):

Don't put things in that way. Wait means blocking, so answer is no. If I understood correctly your question my advice is to do the opposite: when your thread is done call PostMessage to the window you want notify with some custom message.